# Reach user control inside a datagrid control template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid control template. İt has a usercontrol named **LoadingAnimation** inside it:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="TemplateDataGridPrintAndExport" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Label Content="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" ></Label>
        </Border>
        <Border Margin="0,30,0,0" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="False">
                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll" Focusable="False" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                                <Button.Visibility>
                                    <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                                        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                            <DataGridHeadersVisibility>All</DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                                        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </Button.Visibility>
                            </Button>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtons}" Command="ApplicationCommands.NotACommand" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="../Styles/icons/page_excel.png" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Excel" Grid.Column="1" />
                                        <UserControls:LoadingAnimation HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="btnCustomWaitForExcel" Grid.Column="2" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtons}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Print" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" >
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="../Styles/icons/printer.png" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Yazdır" Grid.Column="1" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1">
                                <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Visibility>
                                    <Binding Path="HeadersVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}">
                                        <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                            <DataGridHeadersVisibility>Column</DataGridHeadersVisibility>
                                        </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Visibility>
                            </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Bound the **ApplicationCommands.NotACommand** to the button at the bottom of the datagrid (named btnCustomWaitForExcel).

And **ApplicationCommands.NotACommand** is bound to a function:

```
  CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.NotACommand, ExportExecuted));
```

In the ExportExecuted method I tried four different method to reach **btnCustomWaitForExcel** inside datagrid template :

```
    private async void ExportExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //1. method
            ((LoadingAnimation)(LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode((DependencyObject)LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(((DataGrid)e.Parameter)), "btnCustomWaitForExcel"))).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            //2. method
            ((LoadingAnimation)(((DataGrid)e.Parameter).FindName("btnCustomWaitForExcel"))).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            //3. method
            bool isfind = false;
            DependencyObject parent = ((DataGrid)e.Parameter);
            while (!isfind)
            {
                IEnumerable children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent);
                foreach (object child in children)
                {
                    if (child is DependencyObject)
                    {
                        DependencyObject depChild = child as DependencyObject;
                        if (depChild.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty).ToString() == "btnCustomWaitForExcel")
                        {
                            isfind = true;
                            depChild.SetValue(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden);
                        }
                        parent = child as DependencyObject;
                    }
                }
            }

            //4. method
            ((LoadingAnimation)((DataGrid)e.Parameter).Template.FindName("btnCustomWaitForExcel", dgrdYonetimRolYetkiRol)).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            //Excell esportation
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExportExecuted_async(sender, e));
            await task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            globalTool.insertError(ex, globalUser.ID, true);
        }
    }
```

I could not change the visibility of the user control. Any ideas to change the visibility of the user control inside a datagrid control template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd method is close but instead of using `FindName()` method on the control, you have to use it on a `ControlTemplate`. In this case you in fact have 2 nested `ControlTemplate`. So firstly you have to find the `ScrollViewer` inside the template of the `DataGrid`. Next you'll find the custom control inside the template of the `ScrollViewer`:

```
LoadingAnimation loadingAnim = null;
var viewer = ((DataGrid)e.Parameter).Template.FindName("DG_ScrollViewer")
              as ScrollViewer;
if(viewer != null){
   loadingAnim = viewer.Template.FindName("btnCustomWaitForExcel")
                 as LoadingAnimation;
   if(loadingAnim != null) loadingAnim.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

The `if` conditions are added following a safe guideline, normally they should all pass and execute the code inside.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply bind the button's Tag to the `btnCustomWaitForExcel` user control itself?  Then, in your command execute, cast the source to the button and then it's tag to the LoadingAnimation control it is and change the visibility.